# Defining multiple dataframes with for loop from list object

Tags: r, for-loop

Very green R user here. Sorry if this is asked and answered somewhere else, I haven't been able to find anything myself.

I can't figure out why I can't get a for loop to work define multiple new dataframes but looping through a predefined list.

My list is defined from a subset of variable names from an existing dataframe:

```
varnames <- colnames(dplyr::select(df_response, -1:-4))
```

Then I want to loop through the list to create a new dataframe for each variable name on the list containing the results of summary function:

```
for (i in varnames){
     paste0("df_",i) <- summary(paste0("df$",i))
}
```

I've tried variations with and without paste function but I can't get anything to work.

Comment: i think what you are actually looking for is `lapply(seq(varnames), \(i) summary(paste0("df$",i)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`paste0` returns a string. Both `<-` and `$` require names, but you can use `assign` and `[[` instead. This should work:

```r
varnames <- colnames(dplyr::select(df_response, -1:-4))

for (i in varnames){
  assign(
    paste0("df_", i),
    summary(df[[i]])
  )
}
```

---

Anyway, I'd suggest working with a list and accessing the summaries with `$`:

```r
summaries <- df_response |> 
  dplyr::select(-(1:4)) |>
  purrr::imap(summary)

summaries$firstvarname
```